# Indexing a collection of xts timeseries

Tags: r, xts

I have a big `xts` timeseries file called 'data_ts'. Plotting

```
plot(data_ts)
```

all works fine. With `{t1,t2}` within bounds, I can also plot the subset:

```
plot(data_ts[t1:t2))
```

However, having 5 subsets I try to collect them in a list (...yes, I'm coming from Python...) using list comprehension (facilitated in R by `libary(comprehenr)`; btw `g(...) %=% c(...)` is Python-like tuple assignment facilitated by `library(tidytidbits)`):

```
data_csv <- read.csv("timeseries.csv", header=TRUE)
segm_csv <- read.csv("ts_segments.csv", header=TRUE)
data_ts <- xts(data_csv$Max.Pressure, order.by=as.POSIXct(data_csv$Datetime))
data_ts_idx <- index(data_ts)
data_ts_segm <- to_list(for (i in 1:5)
  {
    g(m, n)  %=% c(segm_csv[i,1], segm_csv[i,2])
    g(t1,t2) %=% c(data_ts_idx[m], data_ts_idx[n])
    print(str_interp("period segment ${i}: ${t1} - ${t2}", list(i=i,t1=t1,t2=t2)))
    data_ts[m:n]
  }
)
```

Then when trying to plot a timeseries segment the following happens:

```
> plot(data_ts_segm[1])
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
>
```

Apparently, R's `to_list()` doesn't work as Python's `list()`: something happens to the object stored within. Question: how can I index a collection of `xts` objects?

(For the record, the structures of both objects are identical:

```
> str(data_ts_segm[1])
List of 1
 $ :An ‘xts’ object on 2021-01-01 00:10:54/2021-01-22 02:59:07 containing:
  Data: num [1:618, 1] 75.5 71.9 73.5 73.8 73.8 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
> str(data_ts[1:n])
An ‘xts’ object on 2021-01-01 00:10:54/2021-01-22 02:59:07 containing:
  Data: num [1:618, 1] 75.5 71.9 73.5 73.8 73.8 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

)

Comment: The `plot` function is looking for x and y columns in your `data_ts_segm[1]` which it can't find. Hence the error. If the data is allowed to be shared, can you provide some sample data via `dput` and paste that into your question? e.g. `dput(head(data_ts_segm[1], 20)` will provide the first 20 rows of the first xts object inside data_ts_segm.

Comment: @phiver Thanks. I just discovered that the problem is that I misunderstood R's `list` structure, This works: `plot(data_ts_segm[[1]])` (i.e. nested index); indeed, different from Python.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that the problem is that I misunderstood R's list structure, This works: `plot(data_ts_segm[[1]])` (i.e. nested index). R's list is inherently a 2D structure; indeed, different from Python.